# Bijective and holomorphic function $\Omega=\{z: |\arg(z)|<\pi/3\}$

Tags: complex-analysis

I have to construct a bijective and holomorphic function from $\Omega=\{z: |\arg(z)|<\frac{\pi}3\}$ to $D(0,1)$.

I think a possible function is $f(z)=\frac{z^{3/2}-1}{z^{3/2}+1}$. I'm right?

My question is: Is it possible to construct a function satisfying the conditions above that also satisfies that $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=\frac12$? Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I think a possible function is $f(z)=\frac{z^{3/2}-1}{z^{3/2}+1}$. I'm right?

That is correct. $\Omega$ is mapped to the right half-plane and then to the unit disk.

> Is it possible to construct a function satisfying the conditions above that also satisfies that $f(1)=0$ and $f(2)=\frac12$?

Your $f$ already satisfies $f(1)=0$, but $f(2)= \frac{2^{3/2}-1}{2^{3/2}+1} \approx 0.478$. Now use that two conformal mappings $f_1,f_2$ from  $\Omega$ to the unit disk with $f_j(1) = 0$ can only differ by a rotation with a factor of absolute value one.

Comment: Applying Schwarz Lemma, I know that $f:D\to D$ bijective and holomorphic with $f(0)=0$ is necessarily $f(z)=cz$ with $|c|=1$, but I don't know how to extend this to $f:\Omega \to D$ with $f(1)=0$

Comment: Maybe I can reason in the following way: Let $f$, $g$ two confromal mappings from $\Omega$ to $D$. The function $F=f\circ g^{-1}$ is in the conditions of the Schwarz Lemma. So I have $f(g^{-1}(\omega))=c\omega$ for $z\in D$ with $|c|=1$. So I conclude that $f(z)=c g(z)$ for $z\in \Omega$

Comment: @JN_2605: If $f_1, f_2: \Omega \to \Bbb D$ are two such mappings then consider $f_2 \circ f_1^{-1}: \Bbb D \to \Bbb D$.

Comment: Thank you very much, I was just writing that!